# Getting the following error when I run npx cap sync to run an ionic Angular project in xcode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xcode, ionic-framework, terminal

When i run npx cap sync to run my ionic angular project in xcode I get the following error.

```
[!] The plist file at path `/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/project-name/ios/App/App.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`
        doesn't exist.
```

The same also happens if I run ionic cap sync. Have tried recloning the repo and performing a fresh ionic build and ionic cap copy but that doesn't seem to resolve the issue and googling about hasn't helped either. I'm pretty new to angular and ionic so any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to run this project on an M1 Macbook Pro as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add ios to your project ?

```
npx cap add ios
```

Next you have to build your Angular app

```
ionic build
```

And then you have to sync and copy

```
npx cap sync ios && npx cap copy ios
```

I guess the problem is that you don´t have ios in your project.